# getting error could not instantiate class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBGeneratedUuid$Generator",

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

on post request :

{

"txnId": "qwe1",
"umn" : "fef",
"rrn" : "dwdw"
}

Answer (score 0):

Use String field only for id which is auto generated in dynamodb .Int or long will not work .